# Why HTML datalist's option tag not functioning

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet, javascript-injection

As title mentioned, I am thinking is there any error for this part of code:

```js
var td5 = document.createElement("td");
td5.innerHTML = "Locale";
tr3.appendChild(td5);

var td6 = document.createElement("td");
tr3.appendChild(td6);

var tdc3 = document.createElement("input");
tdc3.type = "text";
tdc3.style.width = "100%";
tdc3.setAttribute('list', 'lcl');
tdc3.id = "loc";
var tdc3a = document.createElement("datalist");
tdc3a.id = "lcl";
var lop1 = document.createElement("option");
lop1.value = "MY";
lop1.innerHTML = "MY";
var lop2 = document.createElement("option");
lop2.value = "SG";
lop2.innerHTML = "SG";
var lop3 = document.createElement("option");
lop3.value = "AU";
lop3.innerHTML = "AU";
var lop4 = document.createElement("option");
lop4.value = "NZ";
lop4.innerHTML = "NZ";
var lop5 = document.createElement("option");
lop5.value = "PK";
lop5.innerHTML = "PK";
var lop6 = document.createElement("option");
lop6.value = "PH";
lop6.innerHTML = "PH";
var lop7 = document.createElement("option");
lop7.value = "ID";
lop7.innerHTML = "ID";
var lop8 = document.createElement("option");
lop8.value = "VN";
lop8.innerHTML = "VN";
var lop9 = document.createElement("option");
lop9.value = "TH";
lop9.innerHTML = "TH";
var lop10 = document.createElement("option");
lop10.value = "IN";
lop10.innerHTML = "IN";
var lop11 = document.createElement("option");
lop11.value = "CN";
lop11.innerHTML = "CN";
var lop12 = document.createElement("option");
lop12.value = "JP";
lop12.innerHTML = "JP";
var lop13 = document.createElement("option");
lop13.value = "KR";
lop13.innerHTML = "KR";
var lop14 = document.createElement("option");
lop14.value = "TW";
lop14.innerHTML = "TW";
var lop15 = document.createElement("option");
lop15.value = "HK";
lop15.innerHTML = "HK";
var lop16 = document.createElement("option");
lop16.value = "HK-EN";
lop16.innerHTML = "HK-EN";
tdc3a.appendChild(lop1);
tdc3a.appendChild(lop2);
tdc3a.appendChild(lop3);
tdc3a.appendChild(lop4);
tdc3a.appendChild(lop5);
tdc3a.appendChild(lop6);
tdc3a.appendChild(lop7);
tdc3a.appendChild(lop8);
tdc3a.appendChild(lop9);
tdc3a.appendChild(lop10);
tdc3a.appendChild(lop11);
tdc3a.appendChild(lop12);
tdc3a.appendChild(lop13);
tdc3a.appendChild(lop14);
tdc3a.appendChild(lop15);
tdc3a.appendChild(lop16);
document.body.appendChild(tdc3);
document.body.appendChild(tdc3a);
```

The image below is screenshot after I inject my code into aspx page:
[image: Screenshot]

The image below is screenshot after I inject my code into a HTML dummy page which created by myself:
[image: Expected result]

Additional infomation:
The reason why I writing my code in Javascript is I am currently developing a bookmarklet injector for my job uses. 
I am trying to inject Javascript code into .aspx page to popup a div block with some text field, datalist and drop-down list in it. The browswer I working with is IE 11.
I have tried to inject the original code file into a dummy HTML page which I created by myself and it is fully working without any error, but not in the .aspx page I mentioned just now.
In order to create a drop-down list, We might need to create a select tag and several option tag as child. This works fine in the .aspx page after injection.
But unfortunately, the option tag in datalist tag won't working well as in the screenshot attached above.

Please kindly advise your opinions.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

1. It is necessary to append the `datalist` element to `body` or any other element present in the document, e.g.

`document.body.appendChild(tdc3a);`

2. At the moment browsers seem to ignore `datalists` that are inserted into DOM after the `list` attribute of an `input` is set. Therefore, it is important to insert a `datalist` to the DOM before setting the `list` attribute of an `input`. Example: http://codepen.io/askl/pen/kXZLbj
3. Datalist does not work in all browsers, e.g. Safari and Firefox don't support it as of July 2016. See also http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, the code I attached is a part from my original code. I do have the code you suggested in my original code. FYI, without that line of code, I can't even take a screenshot to attach in my question right?
2. Thanks for recommend a nice website, I bookmarked it just now haha:). I am actually working with IE. Before I trying to inject the JS code into the page, I have tried to inject them into the dummy page created by myself and it is all my code is fully working, but not in the aspx page which I mentioned in question.

Comment: I see in your code where you append your inputs to the DOM of the page but there seems to be no appending of `tdc3a`, the `datalist` anywhere?

Comment: Okay, the line of code added into the code snippet in the question. But my question still the same. Please kindly advise.

Comment: Seems like there is a problem in browsers, at least in Chrome, that doesn't allow the datalist to be inserted AFTER you set the `list` attribute of an `input`. You need to insert the `datalist` into DOM before setting the `list` attribute of an `input` or even before you create the input itself. I created a demo where a dynamically-created `datalist` works fine this way, see http://codepen.io/askl/pen/kXZLbj .

Comment: Thanks for sharing the demo you created, that is very nice. For my current situation, I do able to inject my code into a HTML dummy page which created by myself and the code works perfectly as what I expected. The only thing I don't understand is why the `datalist` won't work when I trying to inject the same code into the .aspx page as I mentioned in the question. 
FYI, I also updated the question with more information that may state my question more detail.

Comment: Does your standalone HTML page use the same JavaScript code as an ASPX page? Try putting this line -- `tdc3.setAttribute('list', 'lcl');` -- to a place AFTER you append the datalist `tdc3a` to the DOM, e.g. make it the last line of your snippet as it is in the demo http://codepen.io/askl/pen/kXZLbj .